# Тест метода на Spock почему NullPointerException

Tags: java, юнит-тесты

написал метод,который проверяет существует ли уже пользователь в системе

```
  public boolean isCustomerExist() {
        return customerRepository.findUserByLoginAndPassword(login,password) != null;
    }
```

использовал для него классы

```
public class CustomerRepository extends AbstractRepository {

    public Customer createCustomer(String login, String password) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setLogin(login);
        customer.setPassword(password);
        entityManager.persist(customer);
        return customer;
    }

    public Customer findUserByLoginAndPassword(String login, String password) {
        try {
            return find(Customer.class, Customer.FIND_BY_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD, login, password);
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            // customer does not exists
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO handle
        }
        return null;
    }
```

пытаюсь написать свой первый тест на Spock но пока идет трудно

```
  class LoginSpec extends Specification {
    private static final String LOGIN_NAME = "test"
    private static final String LOGIN_PW = "test"

    def "IsCustomerExist"() {

        given:' a CustomerRepository'
        CustomerRepository repo = new CustomerRepository(entityManager: Stub(EntityManager))

        and: 'a persisted customer'
        Customer customer = repo.createCustomer(LOGIN_NAME, LOGIN_PW)

        and: 'a Login class'
        Login login = new Login()
        login.setLogin(LOGIN_NAME)
        login.setPassword(LOGIN_PW)

        when:'IsCustomerExist is invoked'
        boolean isCustomerExists = login.isCustomerExist()

        then:'result is as expected'
        isCustomerExists
    }
}
```

почему ошибка

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.eventim.petshop.entities.CustomerRepository.createCustomer(CustomerRepository.java:15)
    at com.eventim.petshop.Login.LoginSpec.IsCustomerExist(LoginSpec.groovy:19)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

private static final String LOGIN_NAME = "test"
    private static final String LOGIN_PW = "test"

```
def "IsCustomerExist"() {
    given: 'a persisted customer'
    Customer customer = new Customer();

    and:' a CustomerRepository'
    CustomerRepository repo = Stub(CustomerRepository) {
        findUserByLoginAndPassword(LOGIN_NAME,LOGIN_PW) >> customer
    }

    and: 'a Login class'
    Login login = new Login(customerRepository: repo, login: LOGIN_NAME, password: LOGIN_PW)

    when:'IsCustomerExist is invoked'
    boolean isCustomerExists = login.isCustomerExist()

    then:'result is as expected'
    isCustomerExists
}
```